# Should I use the Google Architecture Components already?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, googleio, android-livedata

I am starting to build an app from scratch and was deciding on what architecture and tools I should use to start off with since these decisions will typically be affecting us in the long term as well.

In Google IO '17, they just released the Architecture Components i.e. LiveData, Room(for SQLite), ViewModel and LifecycleOwners & LifecycleObservers. I found these components to be a great plus as compared to my previous app. But since these components are still in [alpha](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/release-notes.html#100_alpha_3_-_june_15_2017), is it a going to be a good practice for me to use these components in my android project right now or should I stick with already existing 3rd party ORMs instead of Room and use a different mechanism to update data than LiveData and wait for a couple of months for them to release a stable version of the same? How much time do they typically take for converting it into a stable release?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Better is you should wait until they release a stable version of the above.

Comment: You are asking for opinions ("I am wondering if it will be a good idea..."), which is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's right, I have rephrased it now.